# How to differentiate the driver that will work for 2 identical devices in the same computer?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, drivers, bluetooth

I have 2 identical Bluetooth dongles and i would like to run each of them with different drivers, one of them with the generic Bluetooth driver that windows automatically install, and the other one with the driver I installed using Zadig, the thing is, since they're identical, when i replace the drivers for one of them, windows use the modified driver for both of them, I tried installing the personalized driver with only one of the devices connected, but that also didn't work.

I ask this question not only to know an easy way to do this but also to learn more on how the system treats devices and drivers, thanks in advance to any answers!

edit: if it matters, system is windows 8.1, the 2 devices are bluetooth dongles, one i want to use as regular multi-purpose bluetooth, and the second one as a host for console controllers (ds3 controllers at the moment)

edit2: i've found that this works [Use different drivers for multiple USB devices with identical Vendor and Product IDs](https://superuser.com/questions/1020716/use-different-drivers-for-multiple-usb-devices-with-identical-vendor-and-product) but i still want to know more about devices and their drivers, and how i could change device information to make it unique.

Comment: Since they are identical devices and have the same hardware ID, Windows will use the same driver for both. I don't think what you are asking for is possible. You may want to consider a different BT dongle to replace one of the matched pair if this is an essential configuration to use the special driver with just one dongle.

Comment: isnt there any way to differentiate them, change some type of identifier, name or whatever windows use to differentiate between devices, making them unique from windows perspective?

Comment: The two identical devices use different USB ports obviously, right? Attaching a given driver to a device in particular USB port [seems possible in Linux](https://superuser.com/a/1277343/432690). I hope you'll find similar solution for Windows.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks kamil, i actually found out that it was way easier on my ubuntu pc, but still, windows is my primary drive, and i wanted both bluetooth dongles to stay inside in a 2 usb 3.0 ports i made using a spare header and a short header-to-port board. thanks anyway!